# ng-rupeat ionic - show data in list

Tags: ionic-framework

i am trying to show my data in a list but it does not show up. even i tried to console log my data where i am passing but it dosen't work.

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
<ion-content ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="task in tasksArray" type="item-text-wrap">
    <p>{{task.name}}</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

---

```
  $scope.tasksArray = [
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(result) {
  let tasks = [];
  if (result.rows.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      tasks.push({ name: result.rows.item(i).name, skill: result.rows.item(i).description});
    }
    return tasks;
  };
})
];
debugger
```

everytime i debug it and check scope.tasksArry it gives me something like `[Promise]` thing and not the data i want.
help please

Comment: Hi Nick, can you console.log(result) ? What is the output?

Comment: Can you please add your controller code to here ?

Comment: @MarkoSavic console results give me and object and it i do result.row it gives me what i want but the problem the scope in not returning like result.rows i returning me.

Comment: @SantoshShinde i have updated my code. please take a look

Comment: is it a wrong way to return ?

Comment: @NickBb If this solution works for you, mark answer as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have `[Promise]` as result because `$cordovaSQLite.execute` return promise as result from an async operation.

```
$scope.tasksArray = [];

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(result) {
  if (result.rows.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      $scope.tasksArray.push({ name: result.rows.item(i).name, skill: result.rows.item(i).description});
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following sample code it will help you ..

```
        .factory('DbService', ['$q', '$http','$window','$cordovaSQLite', function ($q, $http,$window,$cordovaSQLite) {
            return {
              getData: function(db,query) {
                         var deferred = $q.defer();
                         var promise  = deferred.promise;
                         var response = {result : '',error : ''};
                         $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query)
                             .then(function(result) {
                                 response.result = result.rows;
                                 deferred.resolve(response);
                             }, function(error) {
                                 response.error = error;
                                 deferred.reject(response);
                             })
                         promise.success = function(fn) {
                             promise.then(fn);
                             return promise;
                         }

                         promise.error = function(fn) {
                             promise.then(null, fn);
                             return promise;
                         }

                         return promise;
              }
            }
        }]);
```

And In your controller use following code,

```
        .controller('DbCtrl', function($scope,DbService) {

          $scope.tasksArray = [];

          DbService.getData(db, query)
                .success(function(data) {
                    if(data && data.length){
                      $scope.tasksArray = data;
                    }
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.tasksArray = [];
                });
          });
        })
```

You have need to handle `[Promise]` as result in `$cordovaSQLite.execute` method.

Please check sample demo to [here](https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/IonicDemoDBApp).

Hopes this will help you !